# Background fetch not working - Not firing notification

Tags: ios, swift, background-fetch

I'm trying to implement Background Fetch API in my app for that I've configured as below.

I've enabled Background Fetch from Capabilities.

In AppDelegate.swift

Added this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(30)
```

Implemented this method too to perform task.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    debugPrint("New notification fired from AppDelegate...!!")

    let notif = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notif.title = "New notification from App delegate"
    notif.subtitle = "Cool App!"
    notif.body = "I liked it!"

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .badge, .alert], completionHandler: { (isGranted, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content:  notif, trigger: notifTrigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    })

}
```

After configuring all the things local notification not firing. Why so?

Am I missing something?

I've also tried [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should request notification permissions as soon as your app launches. You can't request permissions when your app is already in the background.

Comment: permission is already taken for notifications from user.

Comment: So take that code out of this function and get rid of the dispatchQueue.main

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling completionHandler in `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`. I am able to test `BackgroundFetch` with below code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 6.0, repeats: false)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content:  notif, trigger: notifTrigger)

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!)
                        completionHandler(.failed) // Add this line
                    } else {
                        completionHandler(.noData) // Add this line
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can test Background Fetch with below steps:

1. Run your application.
2. Goto Xcode toolbar.
3. Select Debug > Simulate Background Fetch.

Now you will able to Test Background Fetch.

Answer (score 0):

There is similar question about this:

[Background Fetch Does Not Appear to Fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821247/background-fetch-does-not-appear-to-fire/57262301#57262301)

> Try to force it to run on the simulator, If fetch event works in
>   simulator, that proves that everything is correctly set up. There's
>   nothing you can do but wait.